# CSV Comma after every character python

Tags: python, csv

Trying to write to a csv file for an hour. Output problem: Each character has a comma after it. I'm not sure why this is happening since I've done it multiple times before

```
  id_list = []

    with open(outfile1, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0','') for x in f)

        for row in reader:
            temp = row
            try:
                id = temp[3]
                id_list.append(id)

            except (IndexError, csv.Error, KeyError) as e:
                pass

    with open(results1, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for id in id_list:
            try:
                prov_data = getData()
                if prov_data is None:
                    continue
                fab =  prov_data['results'][0]['fab']
                man = prov_data['results'][0]['man']
                serv_type = prov_data['results'][0]['serv']        
                writer.writerows([str(id), str(fab), str(man), str(serv_type)])
            except (IndexError, KeyError,csv.Error) as e:
                pass
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) with [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow).

The problem is that `writerows` expects a list of lists, where each inward list is a row to write.  Since you're giving it a list of strings, it thinks every character in the string is a column in the csv file.

Note that you're also not using `id` in your second for loop, and you are opening a file named `outfile1` for reading, so you may need to rethink your names here.  I would guess you want to replace the `0`s in your second for loop with `id`, but I'm not sure.